# Not getting images from json url link in django

Tags: python, django

i made a simple generic api in django with 3 models
name, image, date. I am getting the url for the image but getting 400 Not Found response.
json response

```
     {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Demo Image",
    "qoute": "I love Yasou.",
    "date": "2016-08-22",
    "card_view_image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/media/images/imageicon.png"
  },
```

and also i have added the media folder in settings.py

Comment: According to the URL, the image should be on your local machine in the folder /media/media/images/, not in necessarily in the folder your .py is located in.

Comment: Check you path, whether it is the valid path where image is store? I can see `media` twice in your path. Is that correct location? 400 error means your object is not found at the requested path